# Planing Active Directory, Sites as OU or not?

Tags: active-directory

I am a teacher who teaches Active Directory and I have been wondering about the following for a while:
When planning a new AD structure, does it make sense to create the locations in the DIT(Directory Information Tree) as OUs? Or is that not a good idea because the locations can be set up as objects anyway? What is a good approach here?

What are the arguments for Sites as OUs?
What are the arguments against Sites as OUst?

Comment: One of the main reasons that Sites and Services exists is to separate the physical structure of the directory from the logical structure. If you want the logical structure to follow the physical structure that's fine, but the logical structure should be designed based on how it is administered.

Comment: thanks! so would you say, that it is bad, to integrate the physical locations(sites) in the logical structure?

or otherwise asked, if i create an ou for a site directly under root and link to a GPO there, is it more or less the same as when i link a gpo directly to a site?

Comment: Not necessarily if that works for your organization.

Comment: I understood your question to be about creating OUs based on a location vs. another model like an organizational chart. Most responses I am seeing here are about AD Sites & Services, because of how the question was worded.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal practice for your sites and subnets configuration to describe the physical network as closely as possible, with site links describing how the individual sites are connected. Done properly, this allows AD to make some pretty clever decisions regarding which DCs to use to service your authentications etc (such as which should take over for a given site if one goes down for a period). In a large enterprise this can be of critical importance. An important point is to make sure you also have subnet objects defined for all your subnets, as the first thing a device does when starting Windows is to try and determine where it is. If it cannot do so, then any DC in your network is then fair game to use for authentication, which can result in very slow performance if you have an underused DC at the far end of a piece of soggy string!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not sure if you understood my question correctly, I wanted to know if the sites in DIT should be created as OU's. I will update the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a right or wrong answer to creating OUs based on a location vs. an organizational chart. Even a combination of both may work. The answer is 100% based on the needs of the organization. Trust me when I say whichever layout you choose will not make everyone happy. In my opinion, OUs should be created primarily for delegation of administrative privileges. The OUs can divide up responsibility for the AD objects when you also create a security group and delegate control of the OU to that group. This takes care of the biggest headache of knowing who manages what.

Other typical reasons for creation of OUs, like applying GPOs or identifying the geographic location of objects, can be achieved in easier ways. GPOs can be applied using WMI filters, security group filtering, or linked to AD sites. Don't create an OU just to apply a GPO, unless that GPO is for population of local administrator groups via Restricted Groups (hint hint). The physical location of objects should be stored in attributes on each object. Query those attributes when you want to know which city or building that user or computer is in. You have little control over people moving from one location to another, and this is why location-based OU structures do a poor job of telling you where something physically is. Sure, the attributes may also eventually be wrong, but updating an attribute has fewer implications than changing OUs.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory gives you a way to divide logical topology from physical topology.

You can define multiple sites, with Domain Controllers in each of them. Sites are mapped to IP subnets, and each computer in the domain can look up the "nearest" Domain Controller based on its IP subnet. You can also manage AD info replication between sites.

You should definitely take advantage of this, because AD is structured to be multi-site and site-resilient.

---

TL;DR: You should ***not*** map your physical sites to OUs, neither use multiple domains. AD is more than able to take care of multiple sites; multiple domains or site-specific OUs are definitely not needed to handle this.

More info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/understanding-active-directory-site-topology